# Need To Resolve Yelp API Response Error: “Signature is invalid”

Tags: api, oauth, yelp

My issue is when I try and fetch the Yelp API I keep getting this error time after time and i'm not sure why i've checked all the parameters and still cant get anything back from Yelp

**My Yelp API Fetch Link -**

https://api.yelp.com/v2/search?term=food&ll=37.788022,-122.399797&*oauth_consumer_key*=**MY_Consumer_Key**&oauth_token=**MY_TOKEN**&*oauth_signature_method*=**HMAC-SHA1**&*oauth_signature*=**TOKEN_SECRET**&*oauth_timestamp*=**1456337018**&*oauth_nonce*=**1456337018**

**My Error -**

#### error: {

```
  text: "Signature was invalid",
  id: "INVALID_SIGNATURE",
  description: "Invalid signature. Expected signature base string:
```

**GET&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.yelp.com%2Fv2%2Fsearch&ll%3D37.788022%252C-122.399797%26oauth_consumer_key%3DG02O6tXnFkSbsGYOJxCQDw%26oauth_nonce%3D1456337018%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1456337018%26oauth_token%3DBPMpqKrD4dA4xGGHKtC_-xitzb5LRNn8%26term%3Dfood"**
}

Answer (score 0):

Error in your API call url,yelp using oauth 1.0a,Which one url parameters should be in alphabet order(this one is telling clearly in your error description), So API call url should be like this:

```
https://api.yelp.com/v2/search?ll=37.788022,-122.399797&oauth_consumer_key=MY_Consumer_Key&oauth_nonce=1456337018&oauth_signature=TOKEN_SECRET&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1456337018&oauth_token=MY_TOKEN&term=food
```

Comment: Still getting the same error 

text: "Signature was invalid",
id: "INVALID_SIGNATURE",
description: "Invalid signature. Expected signature base string:

Comment: {
error: {
text: "Signature was invalid",
id: "INVALID_SIGNATURE",
description: "Invalid signature. Expected signature base string: GET&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.yelp.com%2Fv2%2Fsearch&ll%3D37.788022%252C-122.399797%26oauth_consumer_key=Consumer_Key%26oauth_nonce%3D1456769055%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1456769055%26oauth_token=OAuth_Token%26term%3Dfood"
}
}

Comment: Remove ll=37.788022,-122.399797 from your API request url and check it,If that one works tell me. I'll give the solution. I think problem in url encode.To solve this you need to use %2C instead of ',' in the url. First remove ll and check.

Comment: Getting the same error when I remove ll. When should I use the %2C? Can you send a sample link? Thanks

Comment: Try this(change your keys) and let me know.(remove "ll=37.788022,-122.399797" not "ll" ) https://api.yelp.com/v2/search?oauth_consumer_key=MY_Consumer_Key&oauth_nonce=1456337018&oauth_signature=TOKEN_SECRET&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1456337018&oauth_token=MY_TOKEN&term=food

Comment: I regenerated my keys and tried the link you gave me and still no luck

Comment: Check this,(I remove 'oauth_signature=TOKEN_SECRET') url https://api.yelp.com/v2/search?oauth_consumer_key=MY_Consumer_Key&oauth_nonce=1456337018&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1456337018&oauth_token=MY_TOKEN&term=food

Comment: You need the secret in the url its saying